# Java can't find cacerts

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk, ssl

I've been trying to setup a java dev environment with no luck. I installed `openjdk-8-jdk` but I keep getting `java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty` (when running android's sdkmanager). I've tried updating the cacerts file with `sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh`
 but no luck. `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts` does indeed point to `/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts` but java still can't find the certificates?

Comment: So far I have tried to update the Cacerts and no luck either, sorry I can't help.

Answer (score 14):

Run the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends ca-certificates-java

sudo apt-get install ca-certificates-java
```

Worked for me.

Comment: Had tried a "forced" update before - which disn't work. This, much to my joyful surprise, did!

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue, I linked the old ca certificates from java8 to new openjdk11.
Go to the directory -

```
cd $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11)/lib/security
sudo ln -fsh /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

What I see is, people install the older version of java, link the cacerts.

Answer (score 0):

I have copied the file from original and it worked

```
sudo cp cacerts.original cacerts
```